# Filter RadGrid results and store into a new datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a grid that returns 8000 results, and I would like to filter these results by date and store them into a new datatable and rebind later. I receive this error:

`Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.`

What are my options?

```
if (e.CommandName == "Filter")
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid2.Items)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < RadGrid2.Items.Count; i++ )
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just add a column to your `DataTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (e.CommandName == "Filter")
     {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        td.Columns.Add("Column1");
        td.Columns.Add("Column2");
        //etc.
        //add same columns as you have in RadGrid2

        foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid2.Items)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < RadGrid2.Items.Count; i++ )
            {

                dt.Rows.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

You have to add columns to your DataTable td. Items cannot be added to nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Returning 8000 results to RadGrid is too much.

Please consider using [AllowCustomPaging](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-custom-paging.html), and retrieve only the rows you need to display.

For example, using [Skip and Take](http://byatool.com/utilities/paging-and-the-entity-framework-skip-and-take-part-3/) in Entity Framework.